# Change format of Javascript object/arrays

Tags: javascript

I will illustrate what I want to do with a trivial example. Let's say I have a variable `rows` with the content:

```
[ { id: 1,
    admin_id: 2,
    start_date: Mon Nov 18 2013 07:19:46 GMT-0800 (PST),
    status: 1,
    username: 'Marko Markovic' },
  { id: 7,
    admin_id: 3,
    start_date: Mon Nov 18 2013 07:20:32 GMT-0800 (PST),
    status: 0,
    username: 'Dzoni Noksvil' } ]
```

Now, what I want to create is the following:

```
var gl = { 
        1: { admin: "Marko Markovic" , status: "1" },
        7: { admin: "Dzoni Noksvil" , status: "0" }
    };
```

So, I need to loop through `rows` and, for each row, add a row to the `gl` object according to the rule which i think is clear from the example above.

So I tried this.

```
var gl;

rows.forEach(function(row) {
    gl[row.id] = { admin: row.username, status: row.status };
});
```

The above code throws an error saying `Cannot set property '1' of undefined`. I also tried the following, knowing it won't work but curious as to what error it will throw:

```
var gl;

rows.forEach(function(row) {
    gl.row.id = { admin: row.username, status: row.status };
});
```

And the error was `Cannot read property 'row' of undefined`.

Can someone tell me how to do this correctly and, if possible, the meaning of the errors because I don't know what is supposed to be `undefined` here.

Oh, and please, plain Javascript only, even if jQuery has an easier/better solution.

Comment: Do you really want "gl" to be a plain object and not an array?  You're using numeric keys anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var gl;
```

will initialize `gl` with `undefined` by default. If you are trying to build an object, you have to initialize it with an object, like this

```
var gl = {};
```

Or you can do it with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, like this

```
var data = [ { id: 1,
    admin_id: 2,
    start_date: "Mon Nov 18 2013 07:19:46 GMT-0800 (PST)",
    status: 1,
    username: 'Marko Markovic' },
  { id: 7,
    admin_id: 3,
    start_date: "Mon Nov 18 2013 07:20:32 GMT-0800 (PST)",
    status: 0,
    username: 'Dzoni Noksvil' } ];

var result = data.reduce(function(result, currentObject) {
    result[currentObject.id] = {
        admin: currentObject.username,
        status: currentObject.status
    };
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
{ '1': { admin: 'Marko Markovic', status: 1 },
  '7': { admin: 'Dzoni Noksvil', status: 0 } }
```

[`Online Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/VL8hV/) - It has both, your fixed version and my proposed version.

Comment: Thanks, but after initializing `gl` properly as you said, even though there's no error, doing `console.log(gl)` afterwards just logs `{}`. Is there anything else wrong with my code?

Comment: @jovan if you copied the `.reduce()` code, it puts the result in a variable called "result".

Comment: No, I mean my own code from the question (the first version).

Comment: @jovan Can you please create jsfiddle, so that it will be easy to debug?

Comment: @jovan Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/VL8hV/. It has both, your fixed version and my proposed version.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize "gl"

```
var gl = {};
```

Also, you could use `.reduce` instead:

```
var gl = rows.reduce(function(gl, row) {
  gl[row.id] = { admin: row.username, status: row.status };
  return gl;
}, {});
```

I don't know what your "id" values may look like, but if you're always using numeric keys anyway, it seems to me that you might as well make "gl" be an array and not just a plain object. That way, you'll be able to use `.forEach` etc on it.

Note that the native iterator functions skip over "holes" in the arrays over which they operate. That means that in this case, if you started off "gl" as an array, you'd end up with holes for positions 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6, because you only set 1 and 7. The length of the array would be 8, but a call to `.forEach()` or `.map()` or whatever would only perform two calls to the callback. That's different from something like jQuery's `$.each()`.

Comment: If I do it as an array, would that be by using `gl[row.id]['admin']=row.username; gl[row.id]['status']=row.status;` etc?

Comment: @jovan just initialize it with `[]` instead of `{}`. Everything else would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize `gl` so that it had the value `undefined` when you tried to set a property on it.

```
var gl = {};
…
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support older browsers that don't support native `Array.prototype.reduce` then you can use a regular for loop and new array:

```
var gl = function () {
  var myArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var self = rows[i];
      var obj = {};
      obj[self.id] = {
          admin: self.username,
          status: self.status
      }
      myArray.push(obj);
  }
  return myArray;
};

// output
console.log(gl());
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46Wty)